# Проблема с C++ builder6

Tags: c++

Помогите, пожалуйста. Перекатываю в c++ builder 6 листинг один в один из книги
А.Н.Васильева

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout <<Hello, World!\n";
return 0;
}
```

После компиляции в открывшемся файле `_cwchar.h` красным цветом выделено:

```
using _STLP_VENDOR_CSTD::wcscat;
```

Сама же прога не запускается.

@Андрей, все равно не работает.
[[@Soon](/users/3070/soon)](/users/3070/soon), препод именно по этой проге проверяет.

Comment: Сносите bilder, ставьте тот-же wxDev-cpp(freeware)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   cout << "Hello, World!\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: если я правильно понял - Вы пропустили кавычки

Comment: @Dimitry273 попробуйте переустановить c++ builder6, или скомпилировать с помощью другого компилятора - у преподавателя с "c++ builder6" скорее всего все нормально

Answer (score 1):

[@denisoleshenko](/users/3651/denisoleshenko)
К сожалению не могу отправлять комментарии, так что оставлю как ответ. 
Во-первых, iostream подключается именно БЕЗ .h
Во-вторых, могу предположить, что вы используете borland-овый компилятор. У него всегда были проблемы с заголовочными файлами. И с использованием STD::. И с использованием int main(). И вообще, по сути он не поддерживает стандартизированый c++. 
В-третьих, если не верите - почитайте стандарт. И отучивайтесь писать iostream.h

Answer (score 1):

Судя по return 0; это консольное приложение:

> `File->New->Other->Console Wizаrd->ok->C++->ok.`

только перед return 0; поставьте:

```
system("pause");
```

а то не увидите результата работы программы, еще кавычки здесь забыли:

```
cout <<"Hello, World!\n";
```

Answer (score -2):

Во-первых, после указания библиотеки нету формата *.h. Должно быть так

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

и + мой компилятор выдает синтаксическую ошибку во второй строке!

Comment: виноват..цикла нету(